# cumulant problem

Tags: cumulants

A couple of days after [I posted this to stackexchange](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/117075/problem-of-cumulants), no one's answered:

I take the problem of cumulants to be this: given a sequence $(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots)$ of real numbers, is it the sequence of cumulants of some probability distribution?  In one sense, this is trivially equivalent to the problem of moments: the $n$th moment is a polynomial in the first $n$ cumulants and vice-versa.  But cumulant sequences have a nice property that moment sequences don't have: the set of all such sequences is closed under addition.  So draw a ray out from the origin $(0,0,0,\ldots)$.  If the ray bumps into a cumulant sequence $(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots)$, then $2(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots),3(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots),\ldots$ are also cumulant sequences.

For infinitely divisible distributions, for every real $t\ge 0$, the sequence $t(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots)$ is a cumulant sequence.

Besides the nonnegative integers and the nonnegative reals, there are other sets of nonnegative reals closed under addition.

For which sets $T$ of nonnegative reals that are closed under addition is it the case that for some cumulant sequence $(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots)$, for every real $t\ge 0$,
$$
t\in T \quad\text{iff}\quad t(\kappa_1,\kappa_2,\kappa_3,\ldots)\text{ is a cumulant sequence ?}
$$

I'm guessing only closed sets, but there should be more than that to say about it, I would think.  Even describing or classifying the (topologically) closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^+$ that are closed under addition might be something of a chore, and I suspect many of them are not of this form.

That moderately complicated things might happen is at least hinted at by the case of $p\times p$ Wishart matrices, for which the number of degrees of freedom can be anywhere in the set $\lbrace 0,\dots,p-1\rbrace\cup (p-1,\infty)$.  But that's for matrix-valued, rather than real-valued, random variables, so it's at most a hint.

Comment: Can you include a link to the stackexchange question? Have you left a link there to the MO version?

Comment: Done. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: One condition mentioned on Wikipedia (the source of all truth), is that the cumulant generating function can't be a polynomial of degree greater than 2.  (The normal distribution manages degree 2.) So you can't have finite number of non-zero cumulants except in some special cases.

Comment: ....and those special cases are the ones where all cumulants of degree $3$ or higher are $0$.  If any cumulant of degree $\ge3$ is non-zero, then infinitely many are non-zero.  However, this question is about the set of values of $t\ge 0$ for which $t\kappa$ is a cumulant sequence.

Comment: The moment problem is solved and understood to a certain extent. See https://arxiv.org/pdf/2008.12698.pdf. I'm also looking for if there's a nice translation in terms of cumulants though..

Answer (score 7):

This quote might explain why your question on MSE went unanswered:

> There is one obstacle that stands in the way of dealing with
>   cumulants. We do not know simple necessary and sufficient inequalities
>   on cumulants that ensure that a given sequence of real numbers is the
>   sequence of cumulants of a random variable. For characteristic
>   functions, such a necessary and sufficient condition is Bochner's
>   theorem. To be sure, such inequalities exist in abundance if one
>   expresses moments in terms of cumulants. The problem is finding the
>   simplest such inequalities. The explicit determination of fundamental
>   inequalities satisfied by the cumulants of a random variable is surely
>   the most important open problem in probability theory.

Gian-Carlo Rota, 1998: [Twelve problems in probability no one likes to bring up](http://www.researchgate.net/profile/Andrea_Brini/publication/227080014_A_Glimpse_of_Vector_Invariant_Theory._The_Points_of_View_of_Weyl_Rota_De_Concini_and_Procesi_and_Grosshans/links/00b7d52dd55ffe95e6000000.pdf) - *Problem eleven: cumulants.*

A status update has been given by Di Nardo and Senato, 2009, unfortunately behind a [pay wall.](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-0-387-88753-1_6)

Comment: Unfortunately G-C Rota passed taking away with him potential explanations of many mysterious statements like the one in the quote above...Somewhat related is this MO question: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/107526/reference-request-a-conjecture-of-rota-on-positive-functions-of-a-random-variab

Comment: Rota intended to expand that paper to something twice as long.

Comment: While Rota was writing that paper it grew from 10 problems to 14 and then contracted to 12.  He published a number of top-10 lists not long before he died, including "Ten lessons I wish I had been taught" and some others.  He wrote something called something like "Ten observations on teaching differential equations" but I don't know if he ever published it.

Comment: @Michael Hardy: Published or not, here it is:  https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Rota.pdf

Comment: and I note the Di Nardo & Senato paper has emerged from behind the paywall on [ResearchGate](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/227172143_The_Eleventh_and_Twelveth_Problems_of_Rota%27s_Fubini_Lectures_from_Cumulants_to_Free_Probability_Theory_Invited_Chapter)

Comment: QUOTE FROM THE FIRST PARAGRAPH: One of many mistakes of my youth was writing a textbook in ordinary differential equations. It set me back several years in my career in mathematics. However, it had a redeeming feature: it led me to realize that I had no idea what a differential equation is. The more I teach differential equations, the less I understand the mystery of differential equations. END QUOTE $\qquad$

Comment: QUOTE FROM A LATER PARAGRAPH: The Administrative Director of the MIT mathematics department, who exercises supreme authority upon the faculty’s teaching, has only to wave a copy of my book at me, while staring at me in silence. At her prompting, I bow and fall into line; I will be the lecturer in the dreaded course for one more year, and I will repeat the mistakes I have been making every year since I first taught differential equations in 1958. END QUOTE The said administrative directore, Joanne Jonson (or Jonnson, or Jonsonn, or something else like that with no "h"), told me$\,\ldots\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$that that assertion bore no resemblance to the truth. $\qquad$

Comment: IMPORTANT QUOTE: Teaching a subject of which no honest examples can be given is, in my opinion, demoralizing. END QUOTE $\qquad$

Comment: QUOTE: every differential polynomial in the two solutions of a second order linear differential equation which is independent of the choice of a basis of solutions equals a polynomial in the Wronskian and in the coefficients of the differential equation (this is the differential equations analogue of the fundamental theorem on symmetric functions END QUOTE $\qquad$